# JS: Output the content of the console log

Tags: javascript

I'm using the console log to record any errors in a HTML/JS web application. Is there a way to output the contents of the console log?

For instance, lets say we log "Hello world" `console.log('Hello world');`

Is there a way I can get back what's been logged at a later time? Something like:

```
alert(console.log());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can overwrite the `log` method of the `console` object. `console.log = function() { // store the logged data }`, however you have only access to the manually logged data not those that are generated by browser. You may find this library useful, https://github.com/occ/TraceKit

Comment: Thanks @JAAulde. For later output, would you suggest storing all the logs in a single variable and appending to that variable each time an error is logged?

Comment: I'd push entries onto an array as I go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console provides a log method which does nothing other than write your message into the console output in real time. You can see this in the developer tools of many browsers.

There is no way to ask the native console for a list of things logged. You would need to write something yourself, perhaps augmenting the native console.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

Check this link for the full [Console API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject_object) for Google Chrome. Other browsers have their own console API, but they're generally the same.